# Selected items of listview checkbox in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, listviewitem

I want to pass selected items of listview checkbox in view model, later I will use further process to store in database.

Code in the FormWeek.xaml as

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="TaskExecDefModel"></Binding>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate">
                    <CheckBox
                x:Name="checkbox"
                Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding CheckBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=checkedListView, Path=SelectedItems}"                    
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="selectAll" Content="Select all" Click="OnSelectAllChanged"/>            

<ListView x:Name="checkedListView" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfDays}"  DataContext="{Binding}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}" SelectedValue="WorkingDay"
                      CheckBox.Unchecked="OnUncheckItem" SelectionChanged="SelectDays" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems}">                    
            </ListView>

    </StackPanel>
```

Code in FormWeek.xaml.cs

```
 private void SelectDays(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (this.DataContext as TaskExecDefinitionViewModel).OnCheckBoxCommand(checkedListView.SelectedItems,true);

        }
```

My View Model TaskWeek.cs as follows

//Declaration

```
private RelayCommand<object> _checkBoxCommand;

public ObservableCollection<string> CollectionOfDays { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedItems { get; set; }

 public RelayCommand<object> CheckBoxCommand
        {
            get
            {              
                if (_checkBoxCommand == null)
                {
                    _checkBoxCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((args) => OnCheckBoxCommand(args,true));
                  //  _checkBoxCommand = new RelayCommand(() => OnCheckBoxCommand(object args));
                }
                return _checkBoxCommand;
            }
        }
```

//Constructor

```
CollectionOfDays = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

//Method

```
private void GetWeekDays()
        {
            try
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                    {

                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Saturday");
                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Sunday");
                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Monday");
                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Tuesday");
                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Wednesday");
                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Thursday");
                        CollectionOfDays.Add("Friday");                        
                    }));
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "TaskWeek:GetWeekDays");
            }
        }

public void OnCheckBoxCommand(object obj, bool _direction)
        {
            try
            {

                if (SelectedItems == null)
                    SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                if (obj != null)
                {
                    SelectedItems.Clear();
                    StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();


                   if (_direction)
                    {
                        foreach (string item in CollectionOfDays)
                        {

                            items.AppendFormat(item + ",");
                        }
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show(items.ToString());
                   }
                else
                    SelectedItems.Clear();              

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TaskDefinition:OnCheckBoxCommand");
            }
        }
```

And below is button click commond to save the data.

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                Command="{Binding InsertExecDefCommand}"   Margin="5" >
```

Now my requirement is to pass selected listview items to view model through command object. I had done this using following code in FormWeek.xam.cs  through SelectionChanged event as

```
private void OnSelectedItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string item in checkedListView.SelectedItems)
            {
                items.AppendFormat(item + ",");
            }
            string AllDays= items.ToString();
        }
```

But please let me know how to achieve this logic through MVVM. How to get selecteditems in my view model TaskWeek.cs

After R&D and google i had done chages through RelayCommand. In OnCheckBoxCommand method foreach statement is wrong it is passing all days. I want to pass only selected listview item. Please suggest me what is wrong in OnCheckBoxCommand method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my findings;

use this code in code behind of FormWeek.xaml:

```
    private void SelectDays(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    (this.DataContext as TaskExecDefinitionViewModel).OnCheckBoxCommand(checkedListView.SelectedItems,true);
    }
```

And in 'OnCheckBoxCommand': -

```
 public void OnCheckBoxCommand(object obj, bool _direction)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SelectedItems == null) SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            if (obj != null)
            {
              SelectedItems.Clear(); 
              var _list = ((IList)obj).Cast<string>().ToList();   
              if (_direction)
              {
                 _list.ForEach(item => SelectedItems.Add(item));
              }
            }
            else
             SelectedItems.Clear();                           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TaskDefinition:OnCheckBoxCommand");
        }
}
```

Have a nice day man.....keep going.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try something like this

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">
    <CheckBox x:Name="selectAll" Content="Select all" Command="{Binding CheckBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="checkedListView" SelectionMode="Extended"  ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfDays}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
</StackPanel>

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CollectionOfDays = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        CollectionOfDays.Add("Saturday");
        CollectionOfDays.Add("Sunday");
        CollectionOfDays.Add("Monday");
        CollectionOfDays.Add("Tuesday");
        CollectionOfDays.Add("Wednesday");
        CollectionOfDays.Add("Thursday");
        CollectionOfDays.Add("Friday");
    }

    private CommandHandler _checkBoxCommand;

    public CommandHandler CheckBoxCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _checkBoxCommand ?? (_checkBoxCommand=new CommandHandler((param)=>OnCheckBoxCommand(param)));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> CollectionOfDays { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedItems {get;set;}

    private void OnCheckBoxCommand(object obj)
    {

        if (obj is bool)
        {
            if (SelectedItems == null)
                SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            if ((bool)obj)
            {
                SelectedItems.Clear();
                foreach (var item in CollectionOfDays)
                {
                    SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
                SelectedItems.Clear();
        }
    }

}

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: CommandHandler is my custom class that implements ICommand ,if you want to use Command you must have knowledge of this ,it is available on net or you can use RelayCommand.

Comment: Thanks your idea was great helpful.

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked` where is this coming from? The `IsChecked`?

Comment: IsChecked is the property of CheckBox